# Hadoop Data Node not getting started

Tags: hadoop

I am getting the below error when i start the hadoop cluster. I had verified DNS resolution and it works perfectly. Also i am able to ssh to all the data nodes with passwords. I am not able to understand why the data nodes are failing with name or service not found. Name nodes, Journal nodes are starting without any issues. Any pointers to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
16/03/22 12:06:55 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [infl1089 infl1087]
infl1089: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
infl1089: Kernel 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 on an x86_64
infl1089:
infl1087: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
infl1087: Kernel 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 on an x86_64
infl1087:
infl1089: starting namenode, logging to /var/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-infl1089.out
infl1087: starting namenode, logging to /var/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-infl1087.out
: Name or service not knownstname infl1090
: Name or service not knownstname infl1110
: Name or service not knownstname infl1091
Starting journal nodes [infl1087 infl1089 infl1090]
infl1089: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
infl1089: Kernel 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 on an x86_64
infl1089:
infl1087: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
infl1087: Kernel 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 on an x86_64
infl1087:
infl1090: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
infl1090: Kernel 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 on an x86_64
infl1090:
infl1087: starting journalnode, logging to /var/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-journalnode-infl1087.out
infl1089: starting journalnode, logging to /var/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-journalnode-infl1089.out
infl1090: starting journalnode, logging to /var/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-journalnode-infl1090.out
16/03/22 12:07:08 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting ZK Failover Controllers on NN hosts [infl1089 infl1087]
infl1089: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
infl1089: Kernel 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 on an x86_64
infl1089:
infl1087: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
infl1087: Kernel 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 on an x86_64
infl1087:
infl1087: starting zkfc, logging to /var/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-zkfc-infl1087.out
infl1089: starting zkfc, logging to /var/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-zkfc-infl1089.out
```

Comment: Update your post with Datanode logs

Answer (score 0):

This was due to slaves file moved from windows to unix without doing file format conversion. Converting file format to unix fixed it.